# Get list of emails from Outlook 365 in angular add in

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

How can we get offline addresses in angular plugin from outlook 365. I am able to get email from individual mail, but want to get all stored email from address book.

Code to get individual mail address

```
var mail = Office.context.mailbox.item;
console.log(mail.getEntitiesByType(Office.MailboxEnums.EntityType.Address));
```

Comment: Just a note that your sample code is getting the email addresses that are detected in the body of the email. If you want to get who the email is sent to, you should be looking at the Office.context.mailbox.item.to and cc. Properties, as well as Office.context.mailbox.item.from/sender if you want who the email is sent from.

Answer (score 0):

`OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for that out of the box. You would need to use  `EWS` (see [Call web services from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services)) or `Graph API` for getting more information. The add-in is working under the currently selected item in Outlook, so to get more than that you need to use  [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview).

Comment: Confirming this answer is correct. There is no Office.js API to access the address book. Only the emails of that the message is being sent to/from.